# C++, the term/idiom for programming using template

Tags: c++, templates

I keep reading the term :

1. template programming
2. generic programming
3. meta-programming
4. maybe another idiom/term..

for any c++ code that use template, which one is the correct or more accurate term of this?

Comment: Here's a nice article describing (among other things) generic programming: http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html, straight from the guy who invented it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFAIK:

1. ***Template programming*** is just referring to the classic "programming with templates", i.e. "I have a function/class that I want to make usable with any type, I'll just make it template".

   It can also be can also be seen as the "catch-all" category that includes any programming technique that employs templates.
2. ***Generic programming*** can be synthetically described as the programming paradigm used by the STL.

   Wikipedia defines it as

   > a style of computer programming in which algorithms are written in terms of to-be-specified-later types that are then instantiated when needed for specific types provided as parameters

   IMHO, it's better to say that all the containers are designed to be used with any type (without sacrificing type safety) and algorithms are designed to be generic enough to work on any container type (as long as it's sensible to use them, obviously, i.e. it makes no sense to sort an unordered container).

   Notice that *generic programming* (with this definition) does not strictly require the use of templates, in facts it can be achieved with inheritance and dynamic polymorphism (*thanks to Ben Voigt*).

   In general, I'd say that *template programming* and *generic programming* partially overlap, and many people use the terms *generic programming* and *template programming* interchangeably.
3. ***Template metaprogramming*** is a programming style in which templates are used to perform compile-time computations/decisions/checks normally not doable without templates (statical assertions, compile-time constants computations, ...).

   Such code is often quite contrived, since C++ wasn't designed for this style of programming (which was actually "discovered" later), and may look unfamiliar to C++ programmers also because it often gets near to functional programming (without having nice syntax facilities for it) instead of following the imperative paradigm normally used in C++.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that "generic programming" doesn't require templates, dynamic polymorphism using inheritance and overloaded virtual functions also qualifies as "generic programming".

Comment: @Ben: yes, you're right, although generally in C++ doing it with templates it's much more efficient.

Comment: @Matteo: It's not really an efficiency thing -- dynamic polymorhpism supports collections of heterogeneous objects and templates do not.  Sometimes both methods even have to be used together.

Comment: @Ben: doing it with dynamic polymorphism throws type safety out the window though, which means that it no longer works generically. I'd say generic programming is impossible in C++ without using templates. I strongly suspect Stepanov would say the same, and he coined the term. ;)

Comment: @jalf: Subtyping calculus shows that dynamic polymorphism doesn't violate type safety, at least in theory.  Are you thinking of some particular case where C++ doesn't do the theoretically correct thing?  I'd love to hear your example.

Comment: There's Stepanovs pet example: define a simple generic `min` function. Using dynamic polymorphism you end up with something like `Object min(Object, Object)`, which throws away the type info. You don't get the correct type out, just some catch-all base type. For it to be truly generic, it has to work conceptually like `T min<T>(T, T)` (pseudocode)

Comment: Although I guess I should have been more precise. It's not really type safety that's the issue, but rather loss of type information, and the associated loss of generality.

Comment: @jalf: I think that the biggest problem for this approach is that there's not a superclass for every type in C++ (as would be e.g. `System.Object` in .NET) and the lack of late binding, and the primitive types would be somehow cut out from the generic algorithms wrote in this way.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually referred to as **generic programming**.

Template **meta** programming is something else than normal use of templates, in TMP types are manipulated at compile time (see [boost.Mpl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html)).